# How do I update the value in object if the id matches?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

How do I update the title in `data` if the id matches?

```
const data = {
    "0": {
        "id": 1912,
        "title": "Books",
    },
    "1": {
        "id": 1958,
        "title": "Brands",
    },
    "2": {
        "id": 2037,
        "title": "Logo",
    },
    "3": {
        "id": 2038,
        "title": "Colour",
    },
}
```

For example,
This is the object with the latest updated title with the id: 1912.

```
const updatedData = {id: 1912, title: 'The Books'}
```

Sample output after updating `data` with `updatedData`

```
const data = {
    "0": {
        "id": 1912,
        "title": "The Books",
    },
    "1": {
        "id": 1958,
        "title": "Brands",
    },
    "2": {
        "id": 2037,
        "title": "Logo",
    },
    "3": {
        "id": 2038,
        "title": "Colour",
    },
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Object.keys()` to generate an array of the object keys (`[0,1,2,3]`). Loop through that array and check the id at each.

```
const data = {
    0: {
        id: 1912,
        title: 'Books',
    },
    1: {
        id: 1958,
        title: 'Brands',
    },
    2: {
        id: 2037,
        title: 'Logo',
    },
    3: {
        id: 2038,
        title: 'Colour',
    },
};

const updatedData = { id: 1912, title: 'The Books' };

Object.keys(data).forEach((el) => {
    if (data[el].id === updatedData.id) {
        data[el] = updatedData;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As for React, I'd suggest that you should mutate your object for the update.

You can use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to get keys (your indices) and values (your inner object which you want to update), and then use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to populate your `updatedData` on found data with `updatedData.id`

```js
const data = {
    "0": {
        "id": 1912,
        "title": "Books",
    },
    "1": {
        "id": 1958,
        "title": "Brands",
    },
    "2": {
        "id": 2037,
        "title": "Logo",
    },
    "3": {
        "id": 2038,
        "title": "Colour",
    },
}

const updatedData = {id: 1912, title: 'The Books'}

const result = Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) => value.id === updatedData.id ? { [key]: { ...value, ...updatedData } } : { [key]: value })

console.log(result)
```